# Ubuntu is not there after installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

After a lot of trouble with the UEFI-BIOS, my new ASUS 2220, running Windows 8, accepted booting from a live-USB stick with Ubuntu 12.04 on it. Even better: installation of Ubuntu ran without any problem. I wanted to try to make a dual-boot system, just like I had on a equally new laptop.Two partitions of 160 Gig were proposed and accepted.

However, there is no option to choose Ubuntu, the system is stubbornly sending me to Windows. Whatever I try, no way.

I suspect that it has something to do with Win8. On the laptop I tried to do the same after doing the upgrade to Win8, but had to completely reinstall Win7. I tried to find an answer, but the combination Win8 and Ubuntu does not come forward.

Help! Where to look, how to correct this?

Extra question: what does GRUB mean or do? seems to be important, but I can't find the link.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Mari, Thanks for your effort in answerring my question. However, this is not the problem. Secure Boot was already disbaled, being a known issue. F8 and F9 do not work. Before installing Ubuntu from USB, the ESC-key gave acces to that stick, but not anymore. I will probably need to re-install Windows 8, get back to the USB, and install Ubuntu as a single-boot system. Is there anyone around who tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 comes with secure boot turned on, which means the firmware on a motherboard will check, at boot time, to see if the operating system that is trying to boot is genuine; this check is done by means of cryptographic keys. It is ostensibly meant to prevent boot-time malware from infecting Windows 8; coincidentally, it also serves to make it pretty hard for a user to boot any other operating system on said machine.

Press F8 or F9 while the system boots to bring up the boot options. from here you can choose Ubuntu.